# Is there a way to replace a random character in a string with another random character in another string? Python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I'm trying to make a guessing game so that after you guess a character, the dash goes and the actual character gets revealed. This is a simplified version:

```
import random

wrd = input("Enter a word") # Get user input
wrd_len = len(wrd) #Get word length

dash = "-" * wrd_len #Get a string of dashes

rng = random.randint(0,wrd_len) #Get a random number between 0 and sentence length
# This number will be the placement of the character which will be replaced

new_wrd = wrd.replace(dash[rng] , wrd[rng])
```

I tried making entering the place where a random character is, but that isn't working.

I'm a beginner so sorry if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?

```
index_wrd = random.randint(0, len(wrd) - 1)
new_wrd = wrd[:index_wrd] + dash[index_wrd] + wrd[index_wrd + 1:]
```

Comment: Idk why, but it doesn't print anything after the index 3, so if the string is "Batman", it'll print "B-----" or "-a----" or "--t---" or "---m--", it won't print "----a-" or "-----n". Any idea why?